# SCSS mixin for vendor specific attributes

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I'm writing a mixin to handle vendor specific attributes, however I want to be able to specify which vendors I want to support.

I have tried...

```
@mixin vendor($attribute, $value, $vendors: (moz, ms, webkit)) {
    @each $vendor in $vendors {
        #{-$vendor -$attribute}: $value;
    }
    #{$attribute}: $value;
}
```

Resuling CSS...

```
-moz-border-radius: 12px;
-moz-border-radius: 12px;
-moz-border-radius: 12px;
```

I also tried...

```
@mixin vendor($attribute, $value, $vendors: (moz, ms, webkit)) {
    @each $vendor in $vendors {
        #{$vendor -$attribute}: $value;
    }
    #{$attribute}: $value;
}
```

Resulting CSS...

```
moz-border-radius: 12px;
ms-border-radius: 12px;
webkit-border-radius: 12px;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Either I'm crazy, or the second example you're showing worked for you?

Comment: @elad.chen they should be prefixed with a -   like, -moz-border-radius, -webkit-border-radius. The first example contains the prefix, the second contains the vendors. I need a combination of both.

Comment: Oops, Guess I'm crazy.

Comment: @elad.chen Don't worry my friend, it was an easy thing to miss. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your second try:

```
@mixin vendor($attribute, $value, $vendors: (moz, ms, webkit)) {
    @each $vendor in $vendors {
        -#{$vendor -$attribute}: $value;
    }
    #{$attribute}: $value;
}
```

So I just added a `-` before `#{$vendor -$attribute}`.

Comment: Ahh, easy when you know how! Thank you!